# How do I make this dark colored overlay/filter effect and what are these effects called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, photography

[image]

I am trying to make the color effect as seen above. I have considered color overlays but I think its more than putting a color overlay over a picture. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using Photoshop.

Also one more thing, what are these color effects called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use gradient maps buddy. Then use black and red, or any other color that you prefer.

[image: check my screenshot out]